# Is it necessary to have default ctor for the most-base class in virtual inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, default-constructor, virtual-inheritance

## Preliminaries

I am writing a high level library for VMEbus modules. I have two levels of abstraction to represent modules:

---

```
|---------------------|
|        VBoard       |
|---------------------|
| + VBoard( address ) |
| + Init() = 0        |
| + ...               |
|---------------------|
         /\        /\
        /__\      /__\
         ||        ||__________________________
         ||                                  ||
|--------------------|            |-----------------------|
|  VBoardAcquisitor  |            |   VBoardInterrupter   |
|--------------------|            |-----------------------|
| + AllocBuff() = 0  |            | ...                   |
| + ...              |            |-----------------------| 
|--------------------|                       /\
         /\                                 /__\
        /__\      ______ may be _____________||
         ||       ||
.________________________.
|                        |
|        V1785N          |
|________________________|
| + Init() override      |
| + AllocBuff() override |
|________________________|
```

So every concrete module (as `V1785N` in the above UML diagram) is a `VBoard` and has to override the `Init()` function (and some others). Also there are modules endowed with data acquisition functions. For them there is another interface (abstract class) named `VBoardAcquisitor` which is, of course, also a `VBoard`. There may be more intermediate classes (like `VBoardInterrupter`) between the `VBoard` and the concrete module. So virtual inheritance.

## Problem

The crucial moment is that `VBoard` does have only parametrized constructor (parameter is the VME address of a module). And I don't want it to have other one (copy-assignment and copy-ctor are deleted). But when implementing the above scheme in C++ (see **Code** section) I get compilation error:

```
Code.cpp: In constructor ‘VBoardAcquisitor::VBoardAcquisitor()’:
Code.cpp:22:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘VBoard::VBoard()’
             buffer( nullptr )
                             ^
Code.cpp:22:29: note: candidates are:
Code.cpp:8:9: note: VBoard::VBoard(int)
         VBoard( int address ) :
         ^
Code.cpp:8:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
Code.cpp:3:7: note: constexpr VBoard::VBoard(const VBoard&)
class VBoard
      ^
Code.cpp:3:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

### Code

This is the MRE (compiles with `g++ -std=c++11 Code.cpp -o Code`):

```
#include <iostream>

class VBoard
{
    int address;

    public :
        VBoard( int address ) :
            address( address )
    { }
        virtual ~VBoard() { };

        virtual void Init() = 0;
};

class VBoardAcquisitor : virtual public VBoard
{
    int *buffer;

    public :
        VBoardAcquisitor() :
            buffer( nullptr )//problem here
    { }
        virtual ~VBoardAcquisitor() { };

        virtual void AllocBuff() = 0;
};

class V1785N : public VBoardAcquisitor
{
    public :
        V1785N( int address ) :
            VBoard( address ),
            VBoardAcquisitor()
    { }
        ~V1785N() { }

        void Init() override { std::cout << "Init\n"; }
        void AllocBuff() override { std::cout << "AllocBuff\n"; }
};


int main()
{
    V1785N adc( 0x40000000 );
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine if I either :

- call to the `VBoard` ctor *with some random address* in the init-list of the `VBoardAcquisitor`
- define default ctor of `VBoard`

Although I know (checked) that such a call from `VBoardAcquisitor` (the first case) will be ignored I don't like that because I am kind of forced to use some "default" board address and at least aesthetically I am not comfortable with that.

So my question is : Are the only possible "solutions" are those two?

## System

OS : Scientific Linux 7

gcc version : 4.8.5

## Note

Note that it compiles fine with `gcc 7.5.0` **as is** on Ubuntu 18.04. But I don't know why.

Comment: Are you intending to actually default-construct VBoardAcquisitors directly? In the example code, you construct a V1785N, which passes a (presumably-meaningful) address to the VBoard and default-constructs a VBoardAcquisitor. But VBoardAcquisitor is inheriting from VBoard, right? So why not pass that to the VBoardAcquisitor instead and use its member initialization list to set up the VBoard? Is the idea that there might be some classes that inherit from VBoardAcquisitor multiple times but only want to use the single underlying virtual VBoard?

Comment: @NathanPierson, You seem to be right, I think.

Comment: Is a VBoardInterrupter supposed to *be* a VBoard itself, or is it supposed to take action on a VBoard? It might well be that VBoardInterrupter doesn't need to inherit from VBoard and/or concrete instantiations of VBoard don't need to inherit from VBoardInterrupter, if for instance a VBoardInterrupter has a VBoard* member variable representing the VBoard it's interrupting.

Comment: @NathanPierson, Yes, I don't even know for now the implementation of this class, tbh (: . But by the nature a VME board itself is an interrupter. Probably, the question doesn't deal with virtual inheritance. But anyway, it's too late to change things, I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor of `V1785N` should forward the address to it's base class `VBoardAcquisitor`, which itself will forward the address to `VBoard`

Here is the constructor of `V1785N`

```
V1785N( int address ) :
    VBoardAcquisitor(address)
{}
```

and the constructor of `VBoardAcquisitor`

```
VBoardAcquisitor(int address) :
    VBoard( address ),
    buffer( nullptr )
{ }
```

Note that you should not inherit with `virtual` from `VBoard`, so the first line of `VBoardAcquisitor` looks like

```
class VBoardAcquisitor : public VBoard
```

The full code: https://ideone.com/YUeLtf

Comment: I *should* inherit with `virtual` from `VBoard` because as I said in the post a module may be both `VBoardAcquisitor` and, for example, `VBoardInterrupter`. Though, your answer seems to be correct.